# Animating colors in paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

Is there a color delta object in paper.js, which can store negative values in each component?
What I'm trying to achieve here is to animate a color to another color smoothly, by storing the color change in each frame in this color delta object.

Simply subtracting one color from another does not work, as negative values are not permitted:

```
var color1 = new Color(0, 1, 1);
var color2 = new Color(1, 0, 0);
var result = color1 - color2;
console.log(result); // { red: 0, blue: 1, green: 1 }
```

Any suggestions, including easier ways to achieve the same animation effect would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's a known issue that negative components are not allowed. I'm thinking of changing this and moving the clamping of values further down:

https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/271

Comment: I've just fixed that and finally closed the issue. You should be able to use all math expressions with color now:
https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/commit/0dddd897ab3894761b1aab657990cd24b52cb437

Answer (score 4):

There is an [example](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/animation/creating-animations/#animating-colors) on the paper.js website about animating colors.  With minor modifications you could get it to animate from one color to another and then stop.

```
// Create a circle shaped path at the center of the view,
// with a radius of 70:
var path = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 70,
    fillColor: 'red'
});
var finalColor = new Color('blue');
function onFrame(event) {
    if (path.fillColor.hue != finalColor.hue) {
        path.fillColor.hue += 1;
    }
}
```

---

Or, if you would rather stick with RGB, how about:

```
var color1 = new Color(0, 1, 1);
var color2 = new Color(1, 0, 0);
var changeFrame = 0;
var maxChangeFrames = 100;
var path = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 70,
    fillColor: color1
})
function findMiddleColorComponent(comp1, comp2, percentChanged) {
    return (comp2 - comp1)*percentChanged + comp1;
}
function findMiddleRGBColor(c1, c2, percentChanged) {
    return new Color(findMiddleColorComponent(c1.red, c2.red, percentChanged),
                     findMiddleColorComponent(c1.green, c2.green, percentChanged),
                     findMiddleColorComponent(c1.blue, c2.blue, percentChanged));
}
function onFrame(event) {
    if (changeFrame < maxChangeFrames) {
        changeFrame += 1;
        path.fillColor = findMiddleRGBColor(color1, color2, changeFrame/maxChangeFrames);
    }
}
```

If this is the sort of thing you are looking for, my next steps would probably be to create a new object containing the circle, `changeFrame`, `maxChangeFrames`, and the two helper functions.  That way all of the code used to animate the colors would be contained in that one object.

Comment: This code works great however findMiddleRGBColor should return in the format RGB instead of RBG

Comment: Thanks for the catch.

Comment: the `findMiddleColorComponent` function is also often called `lerp` (linear interpolation). Adding this comment to help someone searching for paperjs and "lerp"

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of blending colors from one to another using my library folio.js (https://github.com/frederickk/folio.js) which extends paper.js functionality with interpolate functions (useful for cross blending colors)

http://kennethfrederick.com/folio.js/spectrum.html